# I am trying to send test packets to a crude tcp server but I keep hitting a socket.py error and I dont know how to fix it

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

so I have been trying to send packets from a crude tcp client to a crude tcp server using the instruction from a book (I have very little python experience but I do have programming experience). However whenever I do try to send the packets sometimes it works sometimes it hits an error:

Tcp client:

```
import socket

target_host = "0.0.0.0"
target_port = 9999

# create a socket object
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#connect the client
client.connect((target_host,target_port))

#send some data
client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")

#recieve some data
response = client.recv(4096)

print response
```

Tcp Server:

```
import socket
import threading

bind_ip = "0.0.0.0"
bind_port = 9999

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind((bind_ip,bind_port))

server.listen(5)

print "[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip,bind_port)

# this is our client handeling thread
def handle_client(client_socket):
    # priint out what client says
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)

    print "[*] Recieved %s" % request

    #send back a packet
    client_socket.send("ACK!")

    client_socket.close()


while True:
    client,addr = server.accept()

    print "[*] Accepted connection from %s:%d" % (addr[0],addr[1])

    # spin up on our client thread to handle incoming data
    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(client,))
    client_handler.start()
```

Error:

```
[GCC 5.3.1 20151205]
Python Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[evaluate TCP client.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/TCP client.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.connect((target_host,target_port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

what do I do?

Comment: how many clients do you have talking to the server? I am curious if the server is up when that error occurs

Comment: only the crude tcp client I made, I havent made any others because I just wanted to send test packers

Comment: I had no problem sending them, used your code entirely. worked perfect for me. Are you sure your server was up?

Comment: Is it windows? If so, any anti-virus software is installed and can you check it by disabling anti-virus for a moment?

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was because I had tried to send it to another server with the same name